# Facebook App registration for using 'Facebook login' in a site

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I implemented 'Login using facebook' for my site.
To do so I created an app in facebook and registered it.

The app was sent for review and approval status came as 'live'.
But it also had the following message

"Your App Detail page is live and available in search. Your app does not have enough high ratings and user engagement to be approved for listing in the App Center at this time. Please view our App Centre Guidelines for more information"

The app is still in sandbox mode and unless i get out of sandbox the login feature can't be functional in the site.How do we fix this?

Comment: Sandbox mode and app center have nothing to do with each other, and just for using your app for login with Facebook feature it does not have to be listed in the app center at all. So just take it out of sandbox mode, and you’re good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your app settings!

On your [App Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps), click the "Edit settings" link and set Sandbox Mode to off.